# ARCGIS - map timeout

Tags: java, arcgis

I'm using arcgis for developers in java.
I have a panel with a JMap on it.

In case I don't use (draw, move etc') the map, after some amount of
time the map disappears. If I touch the panel, the map reloads.

I assume that there is time timeout for the map to be visible. Is there? How can I find it? Make it longer?

Thanks,
Aviv.